# How to show that the metric $(X,d)$ is not geometric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The following are taken from $\textit{Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative}$ by Arbib and Manes

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.  The $\textbf{geometry of}$ $(X,d)$ is the set $G$ of all isomorphisms $f:(X,d)\rightarrow (X,d)$ in $\textbf{Met}.$  A $\textbf{geometric figure}$ $\textit{in}$ $(X,d)$ is a subset of $X.$  The geometric figures $A,B$ are $\textbf{congruent}$ if there exists $g\in G$ with $g(A)=B$ (recall, $g(A)=\{g(a)\mid a\in A\}$,) that is "$A$ can be moved to $B$ via the 'rigid motion' $g$".  $(X,d)$ is $\textbf{geometric}$ if all points are congruent, that is, for all $x,y$ there exists $g\in G$ with $g(x)=y.$

Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and define $d:X\times X\rightarrow R_+$ by the table

[image]

Prove that $(X,d)$ is a  metric space, but is not geometric.

$\textbf{Question:}$

I would like to know how to show that the metric $(X,d)$ is not geometric.  I can show that it is a metric.  Am I suppose to construct a function $g$ and use some combination of points to show that $g(d(a,b))\leq c$?  I just don't know how to go about it.  Thank you in advance

Comment: $\textit{Hint}$: the only possible isometry is the identity map.

Comment: @Riemann if it is the identity map, which is what I thought at first, isn't that good enough?  I am thinking along the line of whether i can map one line of fixed length to that of another line and show that they are of congruence.  Maybe I am confusing it with something like triangle congruence here.

Comment: It seems that the morphisms of $\mathbf{Met}$ are distance preserving functions. In the example, show that there is no isomorphism $g$ with $g(a)=b$. This can be done by considering the possible cases for $g(b)$ (which is different from $b$ since already $a$ is mapped to $b$): If $g(b)=a$ then $g(c)=c$ and one gets $d(g(a),g(c))=d(b,c)=2$ but $g(a,c)=3$ contradicting that $g$ preserves distances. I leave it to you to check the other case $g(b)=c$.